# How to output Japanese (EUC-JP) string in Terminal?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal, locale

I have a server with ja_JP.eucjp locale.
To connect, I use Terminal on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop with Preferences-> Compatibility-> Encoding: Japanese - EUC-JP.

You don't need a server to reproduce the problem. It is enough to open a terminal and set locale in it.

```sh
export LANG=ja_JP.eucjp
export LANGUAGE=ja_JP.eucjp
export LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.eucjp
export LC_ALL=ja_JP.eucjp
```

```sh
$ locale
LANG=ja_JP.eucjp
LC_CTYPE="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_NUMERIC="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_TIME="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_COLLATE="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_MONETARY="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_MESSAGES="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_PAPER="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_NAME="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_ADDRESS="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_TELEPHONE="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ja_JP.eucjp"
LC_ALL=ja_JP.eucjp
```

Simple Hello javascript.

```sh
$ cat hello-eucjp.js 
console.log("おい！");
```

But when executed, the encoding breaks, both when outputting to the display and when redirecting to a file.

```sh
$ node hello-eucjp.js 
鐃緒申鐃緒申鐃緒申
```

I have tried encode and decode the string with [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite), but nothing worked.

I would be grateful for any idea or tip.

**UPD**: I changed the title because I couldn't do it with console, but almost did it with fs.write.

I saved the text to a separate file, and read it into the buffer as binary, and then write the buffer to stdout.

```sh
$ cat hello.txt
おい！
```

**hello-eucjp.js**:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const hello_buf = fs.readFileSync('hello.txt', 'binary');
const stdout = fs.createWriteStream(null, {fd: 1});
stdout.write(hello_buf, 'binary');
```

```sh
$ node hello-eucjp.js
おい！
```